# Mongorestore to update records if already exists without --drop

Tags: mongodb, database-backups

I have a huge dump of collection of data which i have to transfer to another machine every weekend. So i'm planning for an incremental backup and restore. As experimented, mongorestore never merges data if _id already exists.
Based on the above problem i tried using mongoimport and export with but the same problem exists as the existing records are not merged. Any possible solution would be helpfull.

> error in mongoimport command caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key
>   error index: news.news_data.$*id*  dup key: { :
>   ObjectId('5404410d9f5323ef734dac68') }

Comment: Are the old records been replaced?

Comment: No. Because of error, old records remain unmerged.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [mongorestore command replace existing records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666908/mongorestore-command-replace-existing-records)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first case is true. Mongorestore does not update documents if already exist. It skips those documents when restoring.
In your second case, please try using mongoimport with --upsert option. It will merge the records if _id already exists.

Example:

```sh
mongoimport --db dbname --collection collname --upsert --file file.json
```

Comment: Be warned that mongoimport imports json, which doesn't have all the type information that mongorestore, which uses bson, will have. Also, I don't quite see what the problem is- if you're transferring a dump, why not drop the old data so there's no duplicates?

Comment: @wdberkeley: some potential reasons for preferring an [upsert](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-121) to a drop + restore: only a few documents are updated in a large collection; not wanting to waste time recreating indexes; emitting only the necessary changes for changeStreams.

Answer (score 6):

Please vote for this [ticket to add an `upsert` option to mongorestore](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-121).

Until that is implemented, we have found a workaround:

1. Dump Collection From Server A ( original )
2. Dump Collection From Server B ( target )
3. Restore With Drop Collection A on Server B  4
4. Restore **Without Drop** Collection B on Server B

In this case updated document will not overwritten