# mongorestore command replace existing records?

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way for mongorestore to replace the records existing in the database instead of skipping it which is the default behavior ?

I'm currently using the latest 2.4.x version of mongodb.

Comment: There is a ticket to enable this feature - [TOOLS-121](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-121).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No. From [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/):

> If you restore to an existing database, mongorestore will only insert into the existing database, and does not perform updates of any kind. If existing documents have the same value _id field in the target database and collection, mongorestore will not overwrite those documents.

If you want to completely overwrite the database or a collection within the database with mongorestore, drop the database or collection **(check [--drop](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-drop) parameter as pointed out by vikas's answer)**. If you want to replace certain documents or merge duplicate documents, then you'll need to write your own script to do the restore and implement the more complex logic yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Although it would be nice for a mongorestore flag to make use of 'save' instead of 'insert'.

Answer (score 116):

You could use [the `--drop` parameter](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption--drop) of `mongorestore`:

> Before restoring the collections from the dumped backup, drops the collections from the target database. --drop does not drop collections that are not in the backup.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. Of course, this is only valid if *all* the documents should be updated.

Comment: Not really *all*, according to docs: *`--drop` does not drop collections that are not in the backup.*

Comment: It is worth noting that while `--drop` will help you overwrite documents, it will also remove all documents in destination collection that aren't in your backup file.

Answer (score 12):

If you have a small collection you could always:

1. mongodump your target collection somewhere else
2. delete your target collection
3. mongorestore the original dump file
4. mongorestore the dump file you made in step 1

This switches the precedence to your dump file instead of to the _ids in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this using

1. restore the collection and write the output to file (errors)

```
mongorestore --db database -c collection ~/path_to_bson > output.txt 2>&1
```

2. filter out the lines containing `- E11000 duplicate key error collection ...ObjectId(...)`
3. then using multi-edit tool (in my case sublime) convert those lines to 
   `db.collection.remove({_id: ObjectId(...)})`
4. restore the database again.

Comment: Why would you do this when there is a native way to do this with mongorestore? Also things like this most likely need to be automated, so you method really doesn't facilitate that.

Comment: as far as I know there is no native way to do it, (upsert functionality is not supported on mogorestore)