# How can i restore a mongodb and replace the existing files?

Tags: mongodb, backup, mongodump, mongorestore

I'm working on a DB migration backing up specific collections but I still need something that could help me to replace the data that could exist in the overturn database, this is the query I'm using:

```
file="listOfBackupFiles.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    # display $line or do somthing with $line
    mongorestore --archive="$line" --gzip
done <"$file"
```

Comment: Do you want to replace existing documents when restoring to a specific collection?

Comment: Yes that´s exactly what i need to do !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongorestore command replace existing records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666908/mongorestore-command-replace-existing-records)